# How to configure R/Exams to use system LaTeX?

Tags: r-exams

I'm completely new to R and R/Exams. I have installed R and R/Exams, and tested the `dist` example to generate HTML outputs. When I tried to generate PDF outputs, R/Exams always used `tinytex` and failed because `Sweave.sty` was not found. I already have TeXLive installed on my system and use LaTeX regularly in my work. I have resolved the problem with `Sweave.sty` being not found by adding the R's texmf to my TeXLive. However, I still want to use my TeXLive installation instead of `tinytex`. Is there a way to configure R/Exams to use the system TeXLive instead of `tinytex`? I'm on MacOS.

Comment: Small update: I removed `tinytex` from R. When I tested creating PDF outputs, R/Exams gave an error "Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘tinytex’" but it still produced correct PDF outputs (I guess using my system TeXLive). I think it'd be nicer to check and use system TeX if available and not give such an error message. Or a way to configure R/Exams to use system TeX that I don't know?

Comment: Maybe the package was not removed cleanly? Or you did not re-start R? Otherwise removing `tinytex` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in `exams2pdf()` and `exams2nops()` is to use `tinytex` when `requireNamespace("tinytex")` is `TRUE`, i.e., when `tinytex` is installed. If you generally don't want to use `tinytex`, simply uninstall it.

If `tinytex` is installed but you still want to use `pdflatex()` from the `tools` package instead, please set `options(exams_tex = "tools")`. You can also put it into your `.Rprofile` if you generally want to set it.

Finally, you can also set up your own LaTeX template for `exams2pdf(..., template = ...)` and omit the packages you don't need - or replace `Sweave.sty`

See also http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/latex/ for more details.

Comment: Uninstalling `tinytex` (cleanly, I checked and restarted R) didn't solve the error message: R/Exams still asked for `tinytex` and showed the error message. Setting the options to "tools" did resolve the problem and made R/Exams use my system LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I now saw the problem in the code and suppress the error message in the development version of R/exams. As you already noted above, the code behaved correctly after removing `tinytex` it just displayed the unnecessary information that `tinytex` wasn't available. Hence, please accept the answer so that the question is marked as resolved here on SO.